# How do I access relation of a relation in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a user, group, group profile, group members, table.

Relation:

```
users belongs to many groups,
groups belongs to many users (name of function is groupMembers),
group has one groupProfile
```

I want to display the groups of a certain user with group profile and group member count.

Currently, I have this:

```
$userGroups = UserView::findOrFail($userId)
                                    ->groups()
                                    ->get();
```

I also have this: it return everything I want, except the fact that it is not user specific. (it returns all groups)

```
        $userGroups = GroupView::with(['groupProfile'])
            ->withCount('groupMembers as groupMemberCount')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Show how the models `Group`, `Group Profile` and `Group Members` are linked

Comment: I agree with Jeune, that we need more information.  However, in response to the general question there are a couple ways to access a relation of a relation.  The simplest is dot notation.  Something like Users::with('Groups.GroupMembers')->get() - but like Jeune said, we need to see the ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$userGroups = UserView::findOrFail($userId)
    ->groups()
    ->with(['groupProfile'])
    ->withCount('groupMembers as groupMemberCount')
    ->get()
```

Laravel relations return a query builder (if you call the function instead of the property) this means anything you can do with a collection of models you can do the same with the collection of related models.